# Can I iterate and update data in ngTable?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

My `ngTable` data is sourced from a `$http` call:

```
$http.get('/book/list.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,
        count: 10
    }, {
        total: response.data.length,
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve(response.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
});
```

I want to change one of the properties of the `ngTable` data when a button is clicked:

```
$scope.markAllAsRead = function() {
    // how do i iterate the data in ng-table here?
}
```

How can I iterate over the 'ngTable' data?

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.tableParams.data` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same as iterating through any other data source for ngTable, through $scope.tableParams.data on click of the button.

Have a look here http://plnkr.co/edit/7F1agWpbREniDqIxCeMk?p=preview

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tableParams.data.length; i++) {
//Do you work...
      }
```

Cheers.